# Calling Angular detectChanges() in an observer causes view update with outdated markup parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have some dynamic inline styles in my template, which determine sizes of some elements in my form. Like:

```
[style.maxWidth.px]='firstInput.nativeElement.offsetWidth'
```

The problem is, that in AfterViewInit lifecycle hook I call detectChanges() method to update the view and then I see my form with proper field sizes which were set dynamically, but when data from backend for this form is retrieved I call detectChanges() again to turn off the loader and my form rolls back to the initial state when field sizes are not calculated.

Any changes afterwards which cause change detection make the template recalculate sizes again.

Example:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.loadData();
        this.detector.detectChanges();
    }
```

```
private loadData(): void {
        this.loading(true);
        this.detector.markForCheck();
        this.service.getSomeData()
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    this.loading(false);
                    this.detector.detectChanges(); // this is where view update is not what I expect
                },
                err => {
                    this.loading(false);
                    this.processLoadingError(err);
                    this.detector.detectChanges();
                });
    }
```

Why detectChanges() inside observer behaves like that?
What can I do to get what I want (update view with calculated styles and update again after data is received to turn the loader off without changing the proper styles I already got).

Thanks!

Comment: Generally you shouldn't need to call any of the change detection methods yourself and doing so from afterViewInit is probably an even worse idea.

Comment: @wlf  What should I do instead then if I have onPush strategy?

Comment: What do you do with 'firstInput' in the component TS file? (Post relevant code) Do you have any other bound properties in your template?

Comment: @wlf this is an element reference and I put initial focus on this element in the component file. Yes, there is a lot of bound properties i.e. on form fields, which can be pre-filled with data I get from db.

Comment: Do you get any browser console errors when executing your code? possibly ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError?

Comment: @wlf yes, I do because sizes bindings change after view children get rendered. Manual change detection call on view init helps, but if there is any other way I can avoid getting this error I would be happy to know it

Comment: No, I don't think there is, I would say you need to rethink your approach as there is a fundamental issue here with modifying the bound style during a change detection cycle. Re your question of not using manual change detection calls, see an example I have created here, note the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError still occurs: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-dynamic-width?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: @wlf thank you for your advice, I will consider changing the design